# Cant find where to edit Sidebar in Athlete Thema

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, sidebar

I cant find the location where my sidebar is located in my webshop. I want to remove some stuff to make the sidebar smoother, but i cannot find the location where it is standing in my scripts. I am using Athlete theme, and searched every file. What is the most common place?

See sidebar here: http://www.thefixedgearshop.com/fietsen-frames/6ku-bikes

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about third party theme

Comment: I have seen your website and which contents from sidebar you want to remove??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove `Newsletter`,`Compare products` and `Twitter sections`.

`Newsletter` you can do this by two process one by removing through corresponding .xml file and other by going to `System->configuration->advanced` and find `mage_newsletter` disable it.

`Compare products:` Add `<remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>`this code in your `local.xml` file.

`Twitter section:` Iam not clear but you can find option to remove this in backend or `local.xml` file

Comment: @AxelDekker accept the answer if it helps so that can be useful to someone who is looking on similar problems

Comment: @don7 where do i do this? Cant find it...

Comment: [look here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) @AxelDekker